# How to remove tooltips in explorer

Tags: windows

How to remove tooltips ?... because of them I can't press buttons ... they always interfere ....
Sorry I speak bad English ...
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggEEG.jpg)

When Moving  the cursor ... to move the window, a tooltip pops up and interferes ...

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XaFn.jpg)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: See https://winaero.com/disable-tooltips-windows-10/

Comment: The tool tip loads when your mouse is over the element it pertains to. They don't often cover the element they actually belong to, but stay to the side of it. Have you tried moving your mouse over a different element? Also, it appears your screen is quite low resolution. Is it possible to increase the resolution?

Comment: No is not that ... it removes information about folders and files - but I need to remove prompts ...

Comment: The hint pops up instantly - yes, you can move the cursor - but it takes a long time ... then you need to go back ... my interface is increased by 150% in the settings - but it's so convenient for me ... the screen resolution is 1920 by 1080

Answer (score -2):

This solved my problem :
https://www.thewindowsclub.com/mouse-hover-time-windows-10

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Mouse   ....
MouseHoverTime (REG_SZ)  ---- set to 400 ( or 1000) milliseconds ... (I have a 20)
Thanks all. Who wanted to help ...

Comment: Link only answer